# position:absolute element messes up fading of another

Tags: css, css-position, opacity, fade

I'm trying to fade a text but it just pops to the end states without fading in-between (partially with delay, too).

I'm using CSS for the fading (`opacity: 0/1` and `transform: opacity`) and, after a lot of debugging I discovered that this was happening due to a totally unrelated `position: absolute` element underneath. Here's a fiddle:

```js
var $root = $('.root');
$('#butt_fadetext').click(function(){
  $root.toggleClass('dermineyda');
});
$('#butt_hidefancy').click(function(){
  $root.toggleClass('nofancy');
});
```

```css
.root {
  background-color: #b87988;
}

.container {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.dermineyda .container {
  opacity: 0;
}

.inn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.unrelated {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nofancy .unrelated {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inn">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unrelated">fancy fx</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="fade text" id="butt_fadetext" />
<input type="button" value="hide fancy fx" id="butt_hidefancy" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned just now that changing an element's [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) can alter its order in the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

> Using this property with a value different than 1 places the element
>   in a new stacking context.

#### Solution

I fixed it by forcing its order upwards in the stacking context.

```js
var $root = $('.root');
$('#butt_fadetext').click(function(){
  $root.toggleClass('dermineyda');
});
$('#butt_hidefancy').click(function(){
  $root.toggleClass('nofancy');
});
```

```css
.root {
  background-color: #b87988;
}

.container {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
}

.dermineyda .container {
  opacity: 0;
}

.inn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.unrelated {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nofancy .unrelated {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inn">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="unrelated">fancy fx</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="fade text" id="butt_fadetext" />
<input type="button" value="hide fancy fx" id="butt_hidefancy" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... There is no point in reinventing the code. You are using jquery so use fadeToggle(...) function.

Comment: `transform: opacity` is pretty simplistic CSS imo. This doesn't feel like reinventing anything. Besides, `fadeToggle()` doesn't seem to work – the text still "pops": https://jsfiddle.net/cmsd87gj/

Comment: [Yes](https://jsfiddle.net/cmsd87gj/1/). Please understand _why_ it doesn't work: `fadeToggle()` doesn't circumvent the problem with the stacking context.